# create online table is not showing in databricks

Tags: databricks

In databricks the "Create online table" field in the drop down menu as in the documentation here https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/feature-store/online-tables.html is not showing up when I try and do it. All I see is that below:
[image]

I am creating a delta table and I look at this table in the hive metastore. Any ideas why I cannot see this in the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the pre requisites as per the docs
[Online Tables](https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/feature-store/online-tables.html)

As online Table is in public preview with Limited capacity & in some regions only. To get access you need to fill the form (link in above doc) and once you get the approval only then you can see the option for using online table

Also for Using online Table below requirements need to be fulfilled

1. The workspace must be enabled for Unity Catalog. Follow the
   documentation to create a Unity Catalog Metastore, enable it in a
   workspace, and create a Catalog.
2. A Databricks admin must accept the Serverless Terms of Service in the
   account console.

Hope that somewhat answer your query.